# What is this insect from Brasil?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image: Photo from SE Brazil Atlantic rainforest Oct 2017[1]]

SE Brazil Atlantic rainforest Oct 2017. I'm assuming this is an early stage of an insect. It was crawling around a tree in the moss and was about 6-7mm.

Comment: SE atlantic rainforest brazil

Comment: I thought maybe a young stage cicada

Comment: You almost got it right: it's not a cicada, but it is close related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is, indeed, a [nymph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nymph_(biology)) (what [you called](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/67906/anyone-know-what-this-insect-is-please#comment122634_67906) a young stage), but not from a cicada as you suspected: it's a nymph from a [leafhopper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leafhopper), which are hemipterans from the Family Cicadellidae (cicadas are also hemipterans, but they belong to the Family Cicadidae). More specifically, this seems to be a [sharpshooter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharpshooter_(insect)), which are leafhoppers from the Tribe Proconiini.

Narrowing down to the Genus is more complicated, but I'd guess it is [*Oncometopia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oncometopia). Here is an image of *Oncometopia orbona* for comparison:

[image]

This other image (also *Oncometopia orbona*) is even more similar to yours:

[image]

Comment: Brillient GF   I have more questions on Brazilian insects to follow.