# ID this insect please. SE Brazil Oct 2017

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image: Rather large 2cm predator fly with extended 'tail']

A number of these large flies were praying on smaller stuff / mid day / in the low altitude rainforest sections of SE Brazilian Rainforest

Comment: Welcome to Bio SE, @BBM56. Here is a tip: if an answer is useful, like [my answer for your previous question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/67906/24284), please accept it. If you don't accept - or upvote - the answers you get people stop answering (I mean I do).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is, for sure, a robber fly ([Diptera, Asilidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asilidae)). My guess is that this one belongs to the Genus [*Promachus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promachus_(fly)).

Here is a photo of *Promachus rufipes* (from North America) for comparison:

[image]

Coincidentally, even the prey (a wasp) is in the same position of the one in your photo!

This Genus has 9 species. If this is in fact *Promachus*, you'll have to find out which are found in South America.